# How to use a shared file from an azure devops repo within an azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The issue is that I'm not able to load just a normal file.
The below code works for extending a azure pipeline file, but I can't use one .runsettings file from the same repository within my vstest step which is in the extended template. Any ideas, how I can share the .runsettings file?

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: service
    type: git
    name: proj/service
    ref: feature/myfeature

extends:
  template: service-template1.0.yml@service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add checkout step:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: service
    type: git
    name: proj/service
    ref: feature/myfeature

extends:
  template: service-template1.0.yml@service
  paramaters:
    repoName: self
```

and then in template

```yaml
# File: simple-param.yml
parameters:
- name: repoName
  type: string

steps:
- checkout: ${{ parameters.repoName }}
......
```